# SSML audio file stops working in final release (but does in Alpha + Beta release) - Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a problem with the final release. The answers given by the assistant are not the robot voice, but its own audio file (in SSML).

An example of the SSML code:

```
<speak>
  <audio src="https://www.voicevitality.nl/public_html/Extra_opnames/Graag_gedaan.mp3">
    <desc>Graag gedaan!</desc>
Graag gedaan!
  </audio>
</speak>
```

This worked perfectly in the alpha and beta version, but when I deployed it to the final release it suddenly stopped working! It displays te text, media, suggestions buttons, but does not play the audio.
I have not changed anything in dialogflow since the alpha and beta release.

Already asked the Google Support Team, but they said to submit a new version for review to see if it breaks in the new version. It did not work.

Does anybody have an idea why it's not working in final release?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you link to the action? If I can reproduce it, I should be able to escalate this issue.

Comment: Hi Nick, https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/000000600575b576?hl=nl_nl&source=web this is the link!

Comment: Is this issue still ongoing? I see that you have created a Dialogflow [public issue](http://issuetracker.google.com/170968726) pointing out this problem. They requested more information from you to properly assess if it is a Dialogflow or Assistant issue. In any case, were you able to reproduce it @NickFelker?

Comment: No I was unable to reproduce the error myself. That public issue may be the next good place to start.